# jenkins pipeline using different nodes for different stages

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to run different stages on different nodes in my jenkins pipeline like stage 1 is checkout, stage 2 is build, stage 3 unit testing. 
For example :

```
node ('linux1')
{
stage ('checkout')
..........
}

node ('linux2')
{
stage ('build')
........
}


node ('linux3')
{
stage ('unit testing')
...........
}
```

If I try to do this, my question is if I checkout code in Linux1 node, how come the other stages can run in different node while the checked out code is in node1.

How the code will be distributed and if my understanding is not correct, how can I achieve parallelism and ensure each stage can parallel and reduce time.

If possible, Please suggest any groovy pipeline documentation for writing Jenkins pipelines.

Comment: Code is not going to managed by itself or by tool itself. You have to plan your steps and pipeline in such that code and other resources utilized and available.

Answer (score 12):

To transfer the workspace between different nodes, use the [`stash`/`unstash`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#code-stash-code-stash-some-files-to-be-used-later-in-the-build).

```java
node('linux1') {
  stage('checkout') {
    checkout(..)
    stash 'name-of-the-stash'
  }
}
node('linux2') {
  stage('build') {
    unstash 'name-of-the-stash'
    sh 'make'
  }
}
```

Due to this overhead of stashing and unstashing, as well as potentially longer execution times when executors are busy (the next node allocation competes with other builds), I would not recommend excessive `node` allocations.

Instead, do as much as you can within one `node` block. You can also mix and match `node { stage {..}}` and `stage { node {..}}` within your pipeline codes.

By design (in Jenkins, as well as in the concept of continuous delivery), stages do not execute in parallel. Only the steps *within* a single stage are executed in parallel.

If you have a stage with long running tasks, use the [`parallel`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-cps/#code-parallel-code-execute-in-parallel) step. This [article](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/230922168-Pipeline-Parallel-execution-of-tasks) could be helpful to further understand this step.

Comment: While the answer remains valid and relevant, the point about stages not executing in parallel is no longer true, i.e. it's now possible to have a (scripted) pipeline with a parallel that includes stages